# ANDROID SQLITE no such column

Tags: android, sqlite

I am inserting this values with that code:

```
     Event evt =new Event("Name","name","uni","name","name","name","name");
      //  Event evtt =new Event("name","name","name","name","name","name","name");
Event evt =new Event("Name","name","Uni","name","name","name","name");
        Event evtt =new //Event("Game","name","Pame","name","name","name","name");
//i change every run the added values

    List<Event> e = new ArrayList();
    e.add(evt);  e.add(evtt);
  DBHandler d = new DBHandler(this);
    d.addEvent(evt); d.addEvent(evtt);

    d.getAllEvents();
   // d.getSomeEvents("Uni");
```

The output is:

```
    Name: Game
                                                               Loc: name
                                                               Type Pame
                                                               Link: name
                                                               sDate: name
                                                               edate: name
                                                               desc: name
Name: Name
                                                               Loc: name
                                                               Type Uni
                                                               Link: name
                                                               sDate: name
                                                               edate: name
                                                               desc: name
```

Error is:

```
database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Uni (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM events WHERE type = Uni
```

It gives outputs correctly, case sensitivte but can not get with specific column. I am only putting codes of 2 methods. I think it is  neccessaryk

```
 public List<Event> getSomeEvents(String type_) {
    Log.e(TAG,"db handler getsomeevents");
    List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS+" WHERE "+KEY_TYPE+" = "+type_;

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    Log.e(TAG,"cursor: "+cursor.getColumnNames());
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Event event = new Event();
            // event.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            event.setName(cursor.getString(1));

            event.setDescription(cursor.getString(7));
            event.setLink(cursor.getString(4));
            event.setLocation(cursor.getString(2));
            event.setType(cursor.getString(3));
            event.setStartDate(cursor.getString(5));
            event.setEndDate(cursor.getString(6));

            // Adding contact to list
            eventList.add(event);
            event.writeSc(event);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.e(TAG,"db handler getallevents sonu");
    return eventList;
}

// Getting All Events
public List<Event> getAllEvents() {
    Log.e(TAG,"db handler getallevents");
    List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS;

     db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    Log.e(TAG,"cursor: "+cursor.getColumnNames());
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Event event = new Event();
           // event.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            event.setName(cursor.getString(1));

            event.setDescription(cursor.getString(7));
            event.setLink(cursor.getString(4));
            event.setLocation(cursor.getString(2));
            event.setType(cursor.getString(3));
            event.setStartDate(cursor.getString(5));
            event.setEndDate(cursor.getString(6));

            // Adding contact to list
           eventList.add(event);
           event.writeSc(event);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.e(TAG,"db handler getallevents sonu");
    return eventList;
}
```

Two methods are same except select from statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the parameter, like so:

"SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS+" WHERE "+KEY_TYPE+" = \""+type_+"\"";

so that the resulting query is:

SELECT  * FROM events WHERE type = "Uni"

Comment: this time another error    Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: fcntl failed: EAGAIN (Try again)

Comment: That is literally another error. Out of scope for this question.